# Thread Name: Is /proc/pid/comm always identical to the Name: line of /proc/pid/status and the second field of /proc/pid/stat?

Tags: linux, proc, process-management, multithreading

A Linux thread or forked process may change its name and/or its commandline as visible by `ps` or in the `/proc` filesystem.

When using the `python-setproctitle` package, the same change occurs on `/proc/pid/cmdline`, `/proc/pid/comm`, the `Name:` line of `/proc/pid/status` and in the second field of `/proc/pid/stat`, where only `cmdline` is showing the full length and the other three locations are showing the first 15 chars of the changed name.

When watching multithreaded `ruby` processes, it looks like the `/proc/pid/cmdline` remains unchanged but the other three locations are showing a thread name, truncated to 15 chars.

`man prctl` tells that `/proc/pid/comm` is modified by the `PR_SET_NAME` operation of the `prctl` syscall but it does not say anything about `/proc/pid/status` and `/proc/pid/stat`.

`man proc` says `/proc/pid/comm` provides a superset of `prctl PR_SET_NAME` which is not explained anymore.
And it tells that the second field of `/proc/pid/stat` would still be available even if the process gets swapped out.

When watching JVM processes, all the mentioned locations give identical contents for all threads (the three places other than `cmdline` all showing `java`), but `jcmd pid Thread.print` still shows different thread names for the existing threads, so it looks like Java threads are using some non-standard mechanism to change their name.

Is `/proc/pid/comm` always identical to the `Name:` line of `/proc/pid/status` and the second field of `/proc/pid/stat` or are there circumstances where one of these three places is offering different contents ?
Please provide an (easy to reproduce) example if differences are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three entries are defined close together in the kernel source: [`comm`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/base.c#L3272), [`stat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/base.c#L3277), and [`status`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/base.c#L3260). Working forwards from there, `comm` is handled by [`comm_show`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/base.c#L1688) which calls [`proc_task_name`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L99) to determine the task’s name. [`stat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L669) is handled by [`proc_tgid_stat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L669), which is a thin wrapper around [`do_task_stat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L467), which [calls `proc_task_name`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L583) to determine the task’s name. `status` is handled by [`proc_pid_status`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.5/source/fs/proc/array.c#L439), which also calls `proc_task_name` to determine the task’s name.

So yes, `comm`, the “Name” line of `status` and the second field of `stat` all show the same value. The only variations are whether the value is escaped or not: `status` escapes it (replacing special characters), the others don’t.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This allows me to use the `/proc/pid/comm` file only and to ignore the others.